# IE9 Loses Some CSS After Particular Form Submit

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

The site I am editing has a search form. For the record, there are several other forms on the site, contact and the like. This is the only one with an issue.

Upon submission of the form, SOME of the styling is lost in IE9 (possibly other versions of IE, haven't tested that yet). Primarily, the margins and colors set in html and body appear to have been lost. Menus, banner, text, etc all appear to retain styles. All styles are on one sheet, that are used here...

Any helpful advice?

Here is the contents of the search page and the php used to check for the form, if that helps, and the css that I think is lost.

EDIT: The page is a search page, with almost nothing on it. A search reloads the same page, while displaying results from the search function. Thus, the same embedded sheets should be embedded, the same html is displayed as far as I can see... if this helps the discussion any. Still sifting to find some type of error. IE dev tools also seem to indicate that this error occurs in previous versions of IE as well, when viewed in IE7-8...

THE HTML:

```
<div id="search">
        <br />
            <div style="float:right;font-size:.8em;">
                <form name="form_sidesearch" action="search.html" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
                <input type="text" name="search_value" value="<?php echo $systems_primary->search_value ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit_search" value="Search Website" />
                </form> <br />

            </div>
    </div>

<?php echo stripslashes($search_results);
```

THE PHP:

```
<?php

// -- Begin Search --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if($_REQUEST["action"] === "search")
{
  if(strlen($_REQUEST["pg"]) <= 0)
  {

  $_REQUEST["pg"] = 1;
  }

  $search_results = $systems_primary->search_website("index",urldecode($_REQUEST["search_value"]),"<div class=\"listing ui-corner-all\"><a href=\"{ENTRY_URL}\" title=\"{ENTRY_TITLE}\" class=\"listing_title\">{ENTRY_TITLE}</a>{ENTRY_CONTENT} <a href=\"{ENTRY_URL}\" title=\"{ENTRY_TITLE}\" style=\"font-size:.8em;\">...read more</a></div><br /><br />",345,"all",10,$_REQUEST["pg"]);
}

// -- End Search ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>
```

THE LOST CSS (could be more):

```
html {
background-color:#F6E6C8;
font-size:16px;
font-family:Helvetica;
}
body {
    width:1027px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family: arial, 'times new roman', sans-serif;
}
```

Elaboration: The actual thing that happens is that the page content as a whole is shifted left and remains left aligned instead of using the auto margins to stay centered. Additionally, the html background color is lost. The styles for the search fields are also lost or ignored. Not sure what else might be altered.

Comment: Have you used Chrome developer tool, or Firebug to see exactly what CSS is lost or being over ruled?

Comment: @Anagio: And that relates to IE how?

Comment: @leppie - Perhaps not Firebug or Chrome's dev tools, but Firebug Lite or IE's own dev tools would definitely help. Also, OP you should make sure you have no HTML errors.

Comment: @leppie if the CSS is changing from the PHP they'd see it in any developer tool. I'd also check to see if there are any conditional comments related to IE that are being overlooked.

Comment: Altered that CSS to make it valid... Trying to sift through the IE dev tools to find out what exactly it's losing. It appears to have the margins still set correctly and the background colors still set too. Does that mean something is overriding it?

Still looking for more info. This thing is a mess, glad I walked into it... thanks for suggestions thus far.

Comment: Times new roman should be in quotes.  "Font" needs to be "font-family"

Comment: @alexy13 yeah, I changed it re: the comment above, just hadn't altered the OP, I'll do that to avoid confusion.

The problem is this: it's the same page being rendered. So it makes no sense that style or even html errors would be the issue since it renders correctly the first time (before the search results are displayed). Unless it's something to do with the formatting of the actual results.

Comment: Is it possible that when you reload the page after form submission and populate the `INPUT` control with the previous submission that there are unescaped characters in the `value` attribute that are invalidating the HTML? (Also, you still have an error in the CSS you have posted.)

Comment: @w3d I don't think so, but that's a possibility, I'll look into it this morning. Also, thanks for the notice on the CSS, forgot that one :D

Answer (score 0):

Typically when styling is lost after submitting a form, especially when it's an Ajax operation and not a full page reload, it's because there was some styling applied using JavaScript or jQuery that did not get reapplied when the updated portion of the page was reloaded. This could involve additional elements being created, or it could involve CSS classes being added to 1 or more elements.

This is especially likely to happen with the styling of HTML form elements, because in some cases heavy styling of certain form elements can only be done with the help of JavaScript or jQuery.

In such cases, identify the JavaScript or jQuery that styled the relevant content when the page first loaded, and then reapply it after the page has been updated (after an Ajax call has completed successfully, or after the browser has reloaded the page or loaded a new page).

Failing that, compare the HTML for the page before and after and see what changed. There may be a CSS class on the body tag or a container class that's not getting consistently set. If a new page is loaded, a different set of CSS files may be getting downloaded, or there may be an embedded style sheet that one page has but another does not.

Failing that, verify that the HTML and CSS are valid. Some browsers are more forgiving than others when rendering invalid code. What may seem like a browser bug could be caused by bad code.

If all of that turns up nothing and it seems increasingly likely that the problem is caused by an obscure browser bug, then reduce the code to the simplest possible state in which the problem can be consistently reproduced, and try to identify more clearly exactly what the nature of the bug is. This will make it easier to search for possible fixes and to ask for help. And in the course of reducing the code, if the problem suddenly disappears, the last code removed may turn out to be at least partly responsible for the problem.

Conversely, when it seems like there's no rhyme or reason to a problem, it's sometimes helpful to reimplement the code from scratch, to see if the problem still occurs. If the problem starts to occur at some point while writing the code, then likewise the last code that was added may be at least partly responsible for the problem.

Comment: Just for information's sake, the CSS isn't being altered by Javascript or jQuery and the page(s) doesn't involve AJAX and isn't loading a separate page.
Checking for valid HTML/CSS seems the next solution to me, although I'm puzzled as to why the exact same code would fail after a form submission but work beforehand.

Comment: If the HTML is only slightly different after the form submission, compare the HTML before and after. If you can identify exactly what's different, and gradually edit the page from one state to the other (using Firebug or editing a local, static copy of the HTML) until the problem appears or goes away, that may reveal the problem fairly quickly.

Comment: Essentially the page has a 'search our site' line and a line telling how many results, if searched. The only new code upon submission is the display of results (regurgitated from a function). Even if I comment out the entire display of results, this still occurs. So frustrating... still looking at the code. I don't have a functioning local copy, as this is built on a (stupid) custom PHP/SQL CMS and I haven't yet arranged a local copy of the install. But it's acceptable for me to tinker on live, as long as I have backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
$('#yourForm").on('submit',function(e){
 $(this).css({
 // reasign all the atributes you lost
 });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```